# Typescript Generic with implicit attribute type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

## Context

I'm having trouble figuring out if I can use implied values for generic arguments in types, the same way that's possible in functions.

Assume I have the following interface defining the structure of some of my database tables:

```js
interface Tables {
  'table-users': { userId: string, username: string },
  'table-posts': { postId: string, userId: string, title: string },
}
```

I can write an oversimplified function that allows me to write to those tables using:

```js
const write = <T extends keyof Tables>(table: T, item: Tables[T]): boolean => {
  // ... do something
  
  return true;
}
```

This allows me to do

```js
write('table-users', { userId: '123', username: 'John Doe' }); // ✅
write('table-posts', { postId: 'abc', userId: '123', title: 'First Post' }); // ✅
```

But not

```js
write('table-users', { postId: 'abc' }); // ❌
write('table-posts', { userId: 'abc' }); // ❌
```

So far, so good.

## The problem

However, now I'd like to be able to construct a type (similar to the function) that takes a property that needs to be a table name, and another property in that type needs to have the correct item format.

I figured something along these lines should work:

```js
type Item<T extends keyof Tables> = {
  table: T,
  item: Tables[T],
}
```

and automatically allow:

```js
const userItem: Item = {
  table: 'table-users',
  item: {
    userId: '1',
    username: 'John Doe',
  }
};

const postItem: Item = {
  table: 'table-posts',
  item: {
    postId: '123',
    userId: '1',
    username: 'John Doe',
  }
};
```

or just use `Item` as function parameter typehint, but it does not, because it always requires explicit definition of the table name:

```js
const userItem: Item<'table-users'> = {
  table: 'table-users',
  item: {
    userId: '1',
    username: 'John Doe',
  }
};

const postItem: Item<'table-posts'> = {
  table: 'table-posts',
  item: {
    postId: '123',
    userId: '1',
    title: 'First Post',
  }
};
```

Any clue if what I'm looking for is possible in TypeScript or not? I figure it should be, because it could be and I'm probably just doing something stupid, but I can't seem to fix it.

## Edit

In contrast, this *is* valid:

```js
type Item = {
  [T in keyof Tables]?: {
    item: Tables[T]
  }
}
```

but I'm hoping to do the same, but use T as a value, not a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of exploration and testing, I think I came up with something that might help you.

If I'm understanding the problem right, you want your `Item` type to have the property `table` be limited to values that match the keys of your previously defined `Tables` Interface.

To do this, you can simply write your Item type as follows:

```
type Item = {
    table: keyof Tables,
    item: Tables[keyof Tables]
}
```

Using this, your `Item` object will have it's `table` property limited to the keys of your `Tables` interface. Similarly, your `item` property will be limited to the values of your `Tables` interface.

This gets around needing to explicitly call out the table name via generic `<>` syntax.

However, This will NOT force your table value to match the item values.

```
// This is allowed, but not expected as table-users doesn't allow for postId
const postItem: Item = {
    table: 'table-users',
    item: {
        postId: '123',
        userId: '1',
        username: 'John Doe',
    }
};
```

If you want your table value to force the allowed value assigned to `Item.item`, you may have to pass the value in explicitly.

Alternatively, you can change the upstream logic so that an `Item` doesn't have to reference it's own table. This would simplify the typing as well.

```
type Item<T extends keyof Tables> = Tables[T]
```

I think the issue at the heart of this question is that `Item.item` would have to reference the *value* of `Item.table` and there is not a way to do that without explicitly providing it via generics. We don't have a way to self-reference the value the user assigns to `Item.table` in order to provide typing for `Item.item` corresponding to that table value.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I appreciate you looking into this. The issue you explain in your example of mixing table name and item structure is indeed what I don't want. I'm also starting to believe that what I want isn't possible. It continues to strike me as odd though that it does work in a function signature (as shown in my example), but then again, with an object you'd have to account for mutations after creation. Thanks! I'll let this one rest.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like so:

```
type ItemGeneric<T> = T extends keyof Tables ? {
    table: T;
    item: Tables[T];
} : never;

type Item = ItemGeneric<keyof Tables>;
```

This will implicitly set the type of `item` based on the string value you set for `table`. [Here's a small demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwEYBsIGdkDeAUAJADkYmOAtAK67S5kBchy90AkgCau5hRQAcwA07BlBBwAthD4DhyAL4jSFKhGoAHAPb8mrAsl38e8wSFHiuvZPwtWwwMDnOKVRJUSJgAnlpROSGkAcQgQaGAEAB5UAD5kAF40ZAgAD0gQbnwAawhfHRg0DXwAfkJSSmw5NABuUmcIaVZ0atwAbVQAXXqlZFYIgDdoep9-QOCk5CCmsIjBGLyCotacXDjR7yIEHRB+aygZ5unJ5OISKtdkdWq6CSZVEkbj85IOQ9syAEYyR7eJKSyVhkABSOgAFiBkAARHQQX6kLxKUY7PZgYx6MBHVhHKbnS41G40ExgB4NYKGUgkElma5fABMAGYESR-jZgT8-u9AYSwZCYXDfsgAPTC5DRajUZBgcHAfDQKA6KD4DAQBBwDjIAAGBO0mNwWuQ3DhuBAFGQqMooGQcG13JkEENMGAECw3ERnnqQA) of this in action.

Full credit to [nmain on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46552#issuecomment-953044832) for telling me about this.